# Error with two grubs on same partition

Tags: kali-linux, grub

So lately I have some problem and I was unable to fix it, so I reinstalled my kali on the same partition with wipe.

But now I have a grub error

```
/boot/grub/i-386-pc/normal.mod not found
```

and I can't fix it. In addition I have windows 10 + kali, but not dual boot - I have it on different partitions.

Can someone help me ??

Comment: Okay I fixed thx anyway

Comment: Congratulations on fixing the error yourself. Please consider posting [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) describing the solution so that others facing a similar problem can profit from your experience.